# How to call function on form submit using jQuery and Validate plugin?

Tags: jquery, jquery-validate

I have an upload form that should display a progress bar while the file is uploading.  The form uses the jQuery Validate plugin to limit file types.

With my current code the progress bar is displaying immediately after the submit button is pushed, even if there is no file selected or the file type does not match.

Any ideas why this is happening?

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    $('#document_upload').validate({

        rules: {
            uploaded_file: {
                required: true,
                accept: "pdf|jpg|gif|png"
            }
        },
        errorPlacement: function(error, element) {
            return true;
        }
    });

    $('#document_upload').submit( function() {

        $('#upload_progress').show();

     });

})
```

Comment: Are you sure you should return true on an error? Try with false.

Comment: @Hidde, this is not relevant, that's only the `errorPlacement`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you getting the correct error message when submitting? I assume so, because the progress bar is showing and thus the form is not sent.

How is the file uploaded? Is it just a standard `<input type="file">` ?

This will always show the uploader on submit, so you'll need to add some checks

```
$('#document_upload').submit( function() {
    $('#upload_progress').show();
});
```

What you could try to add is:

```
if($("#document_upload input[name=uploaded_file]").length >= 1){
    $('#upload_progress').show();
}
```

Can you set-up an example on jsfiddle.net?

Comment: I'm actually not quite sure what the best solution for this issue is, but have a look at this: http://jsfiddle.net/Bzayt/1/. This basically checks if a file has been chosen before showing the progress. You could do the same for the `select`. I must warn you that you mustn't expect something pretty, because the page will redirect. For a pretty uploaders (with progress), you can use a seperate tool like http://valums.com/ajax-upload/ or http://www.plupload.com/